# boton de 2 x 2 imagenes con 4 opciones

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Quiero hacer un bloque que contenga 4 imagenes ordenadas en linea y columna de 2 x 2
Deberia verse sin margenes interior entre las imagenes.
La funcionalidad seria la de un boton grande con 4 opciones que al pulsar fuera a un link distinto cada uno.

Usando "bootstrap" consigo hacer un bloque de 4 x 1

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <div class="view overlay">
    <div>
      <img class="img-fluid inline-block" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(67).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
      <img class="img-fluid inline-block" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(67).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="img-fluid inline-block" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(67).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
      <img class="img-fluid inline-block" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(67).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Si lo hago de esta manera coloco un bloque de 2 x 2 pero me sale separado en vertical y si la pantalla es pequeña el responsive me lo deja en 4 x 1

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="view overlay">
          <img class="img-fluid inline-block" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(67).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <img class="img-fluid inline-block" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(67).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
       <div class="view overlay">
           <img class="img-fluid inline-block" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(67).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
           <img class="img-fluid inline-block" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Mockups/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(67).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues con Bootstrap 5 aquí tienes una solución (seguro con con la versión 4 también va)

he implementado las clases: en el div padre `row` `row-cols-2` `justify-content-center` `align-items-center` y en el div hijo: `col` `p-1` y `style="width: auto;"`

puedes encontrar esto en la [documentación oficial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <div class="row row-cols-2 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col p-1" style="width: auto;"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200" /></div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="width: auto;"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-cols-2 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col p-1" style="width: auto;"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200" /></div>
            <div class="col p-1" style="width: auto;"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Solo queda la parte javascript: añadirle el evento click a cada imagen.

Comment: Hola, intenta que tus ejemplos de código `HTML`, `CSS` y `JavaScript` sea ejecutable mediante la herramienta de fragmento, y trata de incluir en tus respuestas la documentación de referencia del sitio oficial. gracias por hacer crecer la comunidad, Saludos.

Comment: Funciona pero las imagenes deberian hacerse mas grandes o mas pequeñas segun el tamaño de la pantalla donde estuvieran y a ser posible que no hubiera margen interior entre las imagenes.

Comment: Esa separación está puesta con la clase p-1, ponlo a p-0 para que desaparezcan. En cuanto al tamaño de las imágenes puedes usar los media query de CSS para cambiarlo en función de la pantalla o bien ponerles el tamaño como porcentaje del ancho de pantalla con vw (view width: 40vw es 40% del ancho). Por ejemplo .imagenes{width:25%}.